# How does get line work?

Tags: c++, string, getline

I am trying to write my own getline function and it keeps on segfaulting.  How do I fix it and how does get line work officially if mine is not functional? I am writing this to learn how to code better.

```
#include"MyString.h"





MyString::MyString( )  //constructor
{
    size=0;
    capacity=1;
    data=new char[capacity];

}
MyString::MyString(char * n)  //copy constructor
{
    size=strlen(n);
    capacity=strlen(n)+1;
    data=new char[capacity];
    strcpy(data,n);
}
MyString::MyString(const MyString &right)  //
{
    size=strlen(right.data);
    capacity=strlen(right.data)+1;
    data=new char [capacity];
    strcpy(data,right.data);

}
MyString::~MyString( )
{
    delete [] data;
}
MyString  MyString::operator = (const MyString& s)
{

    if(this!=&s)
    {
        MyString temp=data;
        delete [] data;
        size=strlen(s.data);
        capacity=size+1;
        data= new char [capacity];
        strcpy(data,s.data);
    }
}
MyString&  MyString::append(const MyString& s)
{
    if(this!=&s)
    {
        strcat(data,s.data);
    }


}
MyString&  MyString::erase()
{

}
MyString  MyString::operator + (const MyString& s)const
{
    return strcat(data,s.data);
}
bool  MyString::operator == (const MyString& s)
{
    return strcmp(data,s.data)==0;
}
bool  MyString::operator <  (const MyString& s)
{
    return strcmp(data,s.data)<0;
}
bool  MyString::operator >  (const MyString& s)
{
    return strcmp(data,s.data)>0;
}
bool  MyString::operator <= (const MyString& s)
{
    return strcmp(data,s.data)<=0;
}
bool  MyString::operator >= (const MyString& s)
{
    return strcmp(data,s.data)>=0;
}
bool  MyString::operator != (const MyString& s)
{
    return strcmp(data,s.data)!=0;
}
void  MyString::operator += (const MyString& s)
{
    append(s.data);
}
char&  MyString::operator [ ] (int n)
{
    return data[n];
}
void  MyString::getline(istream& in)
{
    char c;
    erase();
    ifstream input;
    while(in.get(c)&&c!='\n')
    {
        data[size]=c;
        size++;

        if(size+1<=capacity)
        {
          capacity*=2;
          char*p=new char[capacity];
          strcpy(p,data);
          delete [] data;
          data=p;
        }
        data[size]=c;
        size++;
        data[size]='\0';
    }

}
int  MyString::length( ) const
{
    return strlen(data);
}
void MyString::grow()
{
 capacity=strlen(data)+1;
MyString temp;
temp=data;
delete [] data;
capacity*=2;
data= new char[capacity];
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, MyString& s)
{

    out<<s.data;
    return out;


}



// int  MyString::getCapacity(){return capacity;}
```

Comment: What line does the segmentation fault happen on?

Comment: For your concat/append operator, don't you think you should resize your data array to be large enough to hold the new string?

Comment: `MyString::MyString(char*)` is not a copy constructor.

Comment: Also, make a member variable to track the size so you don't have to call `strlen()` so many times.  `strlen()` walks the entire string every time to find the null terminator.

Comment: post your header file as well and segmentation faults are due to access violations.you must be using an unintialized pointer which is pointing to some unaccessible location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
void MyString::getline(istream& in)
{
    erase();
    for (char c; in.get(c) && c != '\n'; )
        append(c);
}
```

Now you just need to properly implement a method called append that appends a single character.  If you have trouble with that, then ask another question.  You may think I'm being facetious here, but I am not.  You need to limit the places that you reallocate and stop repeating yourself in your code.  A getline function is not the place for that sort of activity (reallocations, I mean).

Comment: That `for` loop is better off as a `while` loop: `char c; while(in.get(c) && c != '\n') append(c);`

Answer (score 1):

Well...

```
if(size+1<=capacity)
```

Let's say your capacity is 11 and your size is 11.

```
if( 12 <= 11 )
{
   // Resize capacity.  This code won't run.
}
```

You want `if( size >= capacity )`.

Also, you have `data[size] = c; size++;` twice in your loop.  So you're making 2 copies of every character.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyString::MyString(char * n)  //copy constructor
{
    size=strlen(n);
    capacity=strlen(n)+1;
    data=new char[capacity];
    strcpy(data,n);
}
```

There's no point calling `strlen` twice. Optimizers aren't smart enough to eliminate the redundancy. Also, since you aren't altering the data in the passed-in string, it should be `const`. Otherwise you couldn't pass it string constants. Fixing, we get:

```
MyString::MyString(const char * n)  //copy constructor
{
    size = strlen(n);
    capacity = size + 1;
    data = new char[capacity];
    strcpy(data, n);
}
```

---

```
MyString::MyString(const MyString &right)  //
{
    size=strlen(right.data);
    capacity=strlen(right.data)+1;
    data=new char [capacity];
    strcpy(data,right.data);

}
```

`right` has a `size` member that eliminates the need for `strlen`. That plus the fixes above give:

```
MyString::MyString(const MyString &right)  //
{
    size = right.size;
    capacity = size + 1;
    data = new char[capacity];
    strcpy(data, right.data);
}
```

---

```
MyString  MyString::operator = (const MyString& s)
{

    if(this!=&s)
    {
        MyString temp=data;
        delete [] data;
        size=strlen(s.data);
        capacity=size+1;
        data= new char [capacity];
        strcpy(data,s.data);
    }
}
```

`operator =` should return a reference (i.e. `*this`; BTW, you forgot to return anything), not another copy. Also note that `temp` is not used, and you have a redundant `strlen` call:

```
MyString& MyString::operator = (const MyString& s)
{
    if(this!=&s)
    {
        delete[] data;
        size = s.size;
        capacity = size + 1;
        data = new char[capacity];
        strcpy(data, s.data);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

---

```
MyString&  MyString::append(const MyString& s)
{
    if(this!=&s)
    {
        strcat(data,s.data);
    }


}
```

You forgot to check your `size` and `capacity`. So `strcat` will run right off the end of your `char` array. Also, concatenation to itself should be made to work. And you don't need `strcat`:

```
MyString& MyString::append(const MyString& s)
{
    size_t rSize = s.size;
    if(capacity < size + rSize + 1)
    {
        capacity = size + rSize + 1;
        char* newData = new char[capacity];
        memcpy(newData, data, size);
        delete[] data;
        data = newData;
    }
    memcpy(data + size, s.data, rSize);
    size += rSize;
    data[size] = '\0';
    return *this;
}
```

---

`erase` just needs to make the string go away. No memory needs to be messed with:

```
MyString& MyString::erase()
{
    size = 0;
    data[0] = '\0';
}
```

---

```
MyString  MyString::operator + (const MyString& s)const
{
    return strcat(data,s.data);
}
```

Same problems as with `append`, plus this one should return a new object and leave its inputs alone. Also, reuse the methods that have been written so far:

```
MyString MyString::operator + (const MyString& s) const
{
    return MyString(*this).append(s);
}
```

---

```
void  MyString::operator += (const MyString& s)
{
    append(s.data);
}
```

This is an insidious one! See, since `append` takes a `const MyString&` but you're giving it a `char*`, the compiler creates a temporary `MyString`, calls the `MyString(const char*)` constructor on it, passes the temporary to `append`, then discards it. So you get the right result but you created an extra object. The right way is:

```
void MyString::operator += (const MyString& s)
{
    append(s);
}
```

---

```
char&  MyString::operator [ ] (int n)
{
    return data[n];
}
```

No bounds checking? Brave. If you want it, it's not hard to add. Assuming you don't want to throw an exception:

```
char& MyString::operator [] (int n)
{
    if(n < 0)
        n = 0;
    if(n >= size)
        n = size - 1;
    return data[n];
}
```

FYI, the usual type for the index is `size_t`, which is defined in `<stddef.h>` and is the unsigned integer type returned by `sizeof()`, so it's guaranteed to work as an array index with a normal array (here, you could get rid of the negative index check).

Also, you might want a version that can work on a `const MyString`. It just returns the character instead of a reference:

```
char MyString::operator [] (int n) const
{
    if(n < 0)
        n = 0;
    if(n >= size)
        n = size - 1;
    return data[n];
}
```

---

```
void  MyString::getline(istream& in)
{
    char c;
    erase();
    ifstream input;
    while(in.get(c)&&c!='\n')
    {
        data[size]=c;
        size++;

        if(size+1<=capacity)
        {
          capacity*=2;
          char*p=new char[capacity];
          strcpy(p,data);
          delete [] data;
          data=p;
        }
        data[size]=c;
        size++;
        data[size]='\0';
    }

}
```

First, the `ifstream` does nothing; get rid of it. You should only work with the `istream`. indiv pointed out the problems with the extra characters and the bad check. The `strcpy` will fail because you haven't put the `\0` back on the end of the string, so you need to use `memcpy` instead:

```
void  MyString::getline(istream& in)
{
    char c;
    erase();
    while(in.get(c) && c != '\n')
    {
        data[size++] = c;
        if(size >= capacity)
        {
          capacity *= 2;
          char *newData = new char[capacity];
          memcpy(newData, data, size);
          delete[] data;
          data = newData;
        }
    }
    data[size] = '\0';
}
```

---

```
int  MyString::length( ) const
{
    return strlen(data);
}
```

This is just wasting time because `size` already has the length of the string. It really should be defined in the class definition so it can be inlined:

```
int MyString::length() const
{
    return size;
}
```

---

```
void MyString::grow()
{
 capacity=strlen(data)+1;
MyString temp;
temp=data;
delete [] data;
capacity*=2;
data= new char[capacity];
}
```

The first line is simply wrong; `capacity` is already set right. You don't need `temp`. And yu forgot to copy the string data over:

```
void MyString::grow()
{
    capacity *= 2;
    char* newData = new char[capacity];
    memcpy(newData, data, size + 1);
    delete[] data;
    data = newData;
}
```

---

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, MyString& s)
{

    out<<s.data;
    return out;


}
```

You're not changing `s`, so it should be `const`:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const MyString& s)
{
    return out << s.data;
}
```